# Where do I find the OID descriptions for SNMPv2 in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, snmp, protocols

I was looking at this link here: http://www.debianadmin.com/linux-snmp-oids-for-cpumemory-and-disk-statistics.html and noticed that the OIDs are the same ones I see for the same stats for our appliance. Is this some kind of standard with SNMP maybe an RFC or something? Does anyone know where I can find the list that tells me what each OID describes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list you're looking for is most probably at http://www.oid-info.com/

Yes, this is some kind of standard: OIDs are objects in the MIB, the global root MIB was defined in RFC 1155. It has since been extended, the SNMP MIB is [RFC 1157](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157).

Comment: done. I tried to upvote too but It would not let me